# Making subscribers to an Observable to block

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

Learning *Reactive Programming* and *Angular 2* (Typescript) I ran across an unusual use case.

EDIT: here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9mqLTRZSGql4xTPxAqlo?p=preview)

I'm using an `Observable` to show a list of strings and simulate a typewriter effect on them, as follows

```
<li *ngFor="let message of messages">
  <p class="message">{{message | async}}</p>
</li>

export class Component implements OnInit {

   messages: Observable<string>[];

  constructor(private service:Service) {
    this.service= service;
    this.messages = [];
 }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.messageStream()
     .map(
       message => Observable
         .from(message)
         .scan((acc, curr) => acc + curr)
         .zip(Observable.interval(20), (x) => x)
     ).subscribe(
        m => {this.messages.push(m)}
    );
  }
}
```

My service clearly returns an Observable itself and it works like a charm.

Now, I'm wondering how to display **one message at a time**. That is, waiting for the inner Observable to complete before reading the next message from `messageStream`.

I read something about `concat()` and `pause()/resume()` but I'm struggling to figure out how to apply the operators to my situation.

Comment: Is your `messages` an array or an observable `messages: Observable<string>[];` vs `this.messages = [];`. To me this code doesn't make sense. Either it's one or the other. What exactly does **one message at a time** mean?

Comment: `messages` is an array of Observables. I need each message to be an Observable (note the `{{message | async}}`) to display them one char at a time. This code shows each message string with a typewriter effect, but they start being "typed" all together. I would like the 2nd message to start appearing when the 1rt message has been completely displayed.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, I put a Plunker to make things easier to understand.